# how to extract the max numeric substring from a string?

Tags: python

when given a string. how to extract the biggest numeric substring without regex?

if for example given a string: `24some555rrr444`

`555` will be the biggest substring

```
def maximum(s1)
sub=[]
max=0
for x in s1
 if x.isnummeric() and  x>max
   sub.append(x)
 max=x
```

return max

what to do in order this code to work?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Extract the substrings via regex to begin with, or some other tool, and then you can perform the max

Comment: post your code .

Comment: Why don't you want to use `regex` ?

Comment: With regex, it's `re.findall('(\d+)', '24some555rrr444')` giving you `['24', '555', '444']`

Comment: Is the alphabet of the string limited to, e.g., alphanumeric characters?

Comment: yeah, one line using regex `max(map(int, re.findall("\d+", s)))`

Answer (score 2):

Replace all non digits to a space, split the resulting word based on spaces, convert each number to a `int` and then find the `max` of them

```
>>> s = '24some555rrr444'
>>> max(map(int, ''.join(c if c.isdigit() else ' ' for c in s).split()))
555
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use itertools.groupby to pull out the digits in groups and find the max:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "24some555rrr444"

max(int(''.join(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, key=str.isdigit) if k)
# 555
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using regex is wierd, but ok

```
s = "24some555rrr444"
n = len(s)

m = 0
for i in range(n):
    for len in range(i + 1, n + 1):
        try:
            v = int(s[i:len])
            m = v if v > m else m
        except:
            pass

print(m)
```

Or if want really want to compress it to basically one line (except the convert function), you can use

```
s = "24some555rrr444"
n = len(s)

def convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return -1

m = max(convert(s[i:l]) for i in range(n) for l in range(i + 1, n + 1))
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to stay in your mindset, i propose this, it is quite close from the initial demand:

```
#Picked a random number+string stringchain                                                                                                 
OriginalStringChain="123245hjkh2313k313j23b"

#Creation of the list which will contain the numbers extracted from the formerly     chosen stringchain                                        
resultstable=[]

#The b variable will contain the extracted numbers as a string chain                                                                       
b=""

for i,j in zip(OriginalStringChain, range(len(OriginalStringChain))):

    c= j+1

    #the is.digit() fonction is your sql isnumeric equivalent in python                                                                    

    #this bloc of if will extract numbers one by one and concatenate them, if they are several in a row, in a string chain of numbers before adding them in the resultstable                                                                                                         

    if i.isdigit() == True:

        b+=i
        if j < len(OriginalStringChain)-1 and OriginalStringChain[c].isdigit() ==   False:

            resutstable.append(int(b))

        elif j== len(OriginalStringChain)-1 and OriginalStringChain[j].isdigit() == True:

            resultstable.append(int(b))
    else:

        b=""

print(resultstable)
#At the end, you just obtain a list where every values are the numbers we extracted previously and u just use the max function                                               
print(max(resultstable))
```

I hope i was clear. 
Cheers